# Array_column() only picking up last part of array

Tags: php, arrays

For the life of my I can't figure out how array_column() is working differently for my array than it is for the example in the PHP doc.

Here's my array(retrieved from a return):

```
  $array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Category: Test cat 1',
    'value' => '2',
    'tax' => 'category',
    'selected' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Category: Uncategorized',
    'value' => '1',
    'tax' => 'category',
    'selected' => '1',
  ),
);
```

When I output:

```
$a = array_column($array, 'value', 'tax');        
print_r($a);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [category] => 1
)
```

What i was expecting is:

```
Array
    (
     [category] => 2
     [category] => 1
    )
```

I tried making the array like how it is in the [PHP doc for array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$array = array (
  array (
    'name' => 'Category: Test cat 1',
    'value' => '2',
    'tax' => 'category',
    'selected' => '1',
  ),
  array (
    'name' => 'Category: Uncategorized',
    'value' => '1',
    'tax' => 'category',
    'selected' => '1',
  ),
);
```

I still get the same result

```
Array
(
    [category] => 1
)
```

Any explanation as to why I'm not getting the expected array is would be appreciated

Comment: Can't have duplicate keys https://3v4l.org/HgvRJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass third argument in `array_column($array, 'value', 'tax');` like that, it will use third argument as index of the resulting array, in your case you have same value present in the `tax` key of your inner arrays, so that's why it gets replaced by the value from last array.

Comment: Ah thank you! I switched them around and now it works fine, the "value" would always be unique so I can use it as a key.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an associative array with duplicate keys, where PHP doesn't play nice.  It is replacing the first value each time it runs into the same key.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

To make sense of why it "doesn't play nice," try writing your desired output array into a table on a piece of paper, then write what you see back into an array.  I think you'll see what the array should look like (couple ways to write it) and why the way you want it to look doesn't make sense.